# CakePhp Cookie read from other controller

Tags: cakephp, cookies

For some reason I can't read my cookie from other controller. Code is pretty simple, not sure what is wrong with it. It claims that cookie is null...

PagesController:

```
public $components = array('Cookie');

public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        //cookie setings   
        $this->Cookie->name = 'cookie_test';
        $this->Cookie->time = 3600;  // or '1 hour'
        $this->Cookie->path = '/';
        $this->Cookie->domain = 'localhost';
        $this->Cookie->secure = false;
        $this->Cookie->key = '39lbkutg1i2l0kta6785d8qki5';
        $this->Cookie->httpOnly = true;

    }

$this->Cookie->write('ad_id', $ad_id, false, time()+2592000);
```

in NamesearchController:

```
$variable = $this->Cookie->read('ad_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a cookie named `cookie_test` and added a key named `ad_id`. If you look at your cookies (page info or Firebug), you will see one called `cookie_test[ad_id]`.

The first parameter of methods `write()` and `read()` in Cookie Component are `$key`, not the name of your cookie.

So, if you want to read the cookie you created, you have to do:

```
$this->Cookie->name = 'cookie_test';
$variable = $this->Cookie->read('ad_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write the following lines in AppController and not PagesController.

```
public $components = array('Cookie');

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    //cookie setings   
    $this->Cookie->name = 'cookie_test';
    $this->Cookie->time = 3600;  // or '1 hour'
    $this->Cookie->path = '/';
    $this->Cookie->domain = 'localhost';
    $this->Cookie->secure = false;
    $this->Cookie->key = '39lbkutg1i2l0kta6785d8qki5';
    $this->Cookie->httpOnly = true;

}
```